# Tail recursive Clojure function for computing combinations

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have a function that, given a vector, returns all unordered combinations:

```
(defn combination [ps]
  (loop [acc []
         ps ps]
    (if (= 2 (count ps))
      (conj acc (apply vector ps))
      (recur (apply conj acc (map #(vector (first ps) %) (rest ps)))
             (rest ps)))))
```

This works just fine, but seems a bit convoluted to me.

Is there a more straight-forward, idiomatic way to accomplish this in Clojure? I'm happy to use a Clojure core or library function, as this is certainly part of my definition of "idiomatic". :)

Comment: You can replace `(apply vector ps)` with `(vec ps)`

Comment: ... crashes for `(count ps)` less than 2. `(case (count ps), (0 1) (), 2 (conj ... ), (recur ... ))` perhaps.

Comment: Good point. I was just looking at the code and thinking that `(= 2 ...)` was a bit of a code smell. You'll be happy to know that I replaced my function with yours in the program that caused me to ask this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns all selections of two elements taken in order. Another way to do this is ...

```
(defn combination [s]
  (let [tails (take-while next (iterate rest s))]
    (mapcat (fn [[f & rs]] (map #(vector f %) rs)) tails)))
```

This is shorter than yours and is lazy too. But it's likely to be slower.

Comment: Speed is not an issue for me, so this works just fine.

Comment: When I look at this again, the algorithm is virtually the same as yours. I've used destructuring for brevity in the inner loop. And the expression for `tails` replaces both your `loop`/`recur` and your termination test. And, since I deal in lazy sequences throughout, I don't need to accumulate the solutions in a vector or anything else.

Comment: Yes, your code is really nice and concise. Clojure's destructuring is great stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Clojure has *clojure.math.combinatorics* which contains many convenient functions. So arguably the "idiomatic" way to do what you did in Clojure would be to import/require *clojure.math.combinatorics* and then simply call combinations with *n* = 2.

```
...>  (comb/combinations [1 2 3 4] 2)
((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4) (3 4))
```

For this to work you'll need to first add the correct dependency.

As I write this the latest version is: `[org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.7"]`

I did then require it "`:as comb`":

```
(:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as comb]
```

In case you don't want to use *math.combinatorics*, you can edit your question to precise it and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat facetiously ...

```
(defn combination [ps]
  (clojure.math.combinatorics/combinations ps 2))
```

... which is lazy, but [the source code](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/2ede388a9267d175bfaa7781ee9d57532eb4f20f/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/combinatorics.clj#L90) is two or three times as long as yours.

Comment: Thumbnail, are you sure that's not what my code does? It certainly returns the same value as `clojure.math.combinatorics/combinations`.

Comment: No. I'll delete my misleading - ok, downright wrong - comment. I misunderstood the library function without trying it or reading the given example. Tut tut!